# build phonegap release app with debug info

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build, phonegap

I created an app in PhoneGap it's working on debug mode fine but when I generate signed build it's not working so to check if I want to create release apk with debug mode ON in PhoneGap. To generate release build I use the command "PhoneGap build --release android" but with this, I can't debug my app. so tell me a way to create a release build with debug mode

PhoneGap cli: 7.0.1
Android: 6.3.0

Comment: That's a nonsense. A release build isn't made for debug.

Comment: I know that and I'm not asking for publishing release build. my release build is not working properly but everything works fine in debug build so i want to create release with debug info